# How can front-end get the CSRF token generated from the back-end?

Tags: spring, csrf

I'm developing a back-end API of a web application (using Spring Boot). The API authenticates the users using JWT tokens. I have an endpoint for registering an account (`POST /register`).

Since it is a POST method, it requires a CSRF token from the front-end, and I also attach the CSRF token in the header of each response. However, when the front-end wants to call this endpoint, it needs to send a dummy register request first (which would fail) just for getting the CSRF token. My question is: Is there a better way for them to get the CSRF token? Should I create an endpoint `GET /csrf` just for getting the token before registering?

By the way, since I'm relatively new to security in web, I wonder if attaching the CSRF token in every response is a good practice? This is my configuration in Spring:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf()
           .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
           .and()
        .sessionManagement()
           .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
           .and()
        .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/register").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Comment: Yes you could do that, we have done that once. It works. You just have to make sure that your frontend queries that endpoint beforehand. 
BUT i dont know if that is really good practice, so I upvoted this one and am curious about answers :)
And yes that practice is common, the token changes on a request basis so thats fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should send an initial request from frontend to backend to get the initial CSRF token for the current session. Note that instead of sending a `register` request, you can retrieve the CSRF token for the specific user during `authentication/session` retrieval.

Then you can keep the same CSRF token valid for an entire user session. Also, it doesn't make sense to keep the user session validated for more than 3-4 hours in this case. Just send this CSRF token from frontend to backend for other API calls and validate the token in the backend. So you don't need to send it in every response. Here, we send a secure CSRF token from frontend to backend in the request header. This will also improve user experience and won't introduce backend latency of creating a new token every time.

[Here's](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) more you can read about some implementation approaches.